# Long press on list item hangs the UI sometimes

Tags: android, listview

I have a **ListView** with 20-25 item in it. Long press on any item fetches some data from server which includes some text and some images, and displays it. But sometimes this long press event **hangs** the **UI**.
What could be the reason for this behavior?

Comment: can you please post your code ?

Comment: Code is very much inter-related.So wont be able to share it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `AsyncTask` to fetch data from server in Background. The [official tutorial](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html) is pretty helpful.. If fetching data from server and UI both will be in the same thred then your UI may hang.

Comment: I am using AsyncTask to fetch data and UI and fetching data works in diff threads

Comment: Did you call AsyncTask on onClick method of list item?

Comment: I was telling about the method from which you called AsyncTask to fetch data

Comment: AysncTask is handles separately in a class and onLongClick is handled separately.

Comment: So in onLongClick do something so that it will do nothing while it is working already by previous onLongClick called.It may be case where it is called more than once while previously called method is already working with your AsynchTask.